# Planar YUV420 data layout

Tags: c++, image-processing, h.264, codec, yuv

In my project I use [OpenH264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264) codec, which is said to output data in the `YUV 4:2:0 planar` format. After decoding I get **one array** with `width * height * 1.5` elements, which, when displaying, looks like this image:

http://o3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples_webgl/assets/shaving_cream.png

Why there are four areas below the main one (which contains Y - responsible for grayscale - elements ), instead of two, like on my second picture? Is that mean that the format is different or am I wrong and my world just collapsed?

I thought that the resoult should have looked like this:

[image]

Comment: From your image it is not quite clear how you image the U and V samples in linear memory. Planar format means that in linear memory there will be 320x240 U samples and then 320x240 V samples (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV420p_.28and_Y.27V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion). If your image is a representation of how the image should be stored in memory, then your assumption is wrong since the violet box should be below the yellow one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's also correct. But I found the image on Wikipedia a little bit confusing - maybe it's too small to get the idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is exactly the way you assume.  You are just overlooking that there are half as many U and V pixels across the width of the image.  So the even numbered lines of U data are on the left, the odd numbered ones on the right.  Followed by the V data.

To get it arranged the way you want to look at it, the decoder would have to interleave the U and V data.  It doesn't do that.  Just don't start looking at the image until you converted to RGB :)

Comment: Thanks:)! especially for the information about odd and even lines. It makes sense if you want to have the planar representation.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer is totally correct, I'm just adding more information about the conversion to YUV values:

[image: YUV420 Planar]

```
size.total = size.width * size.height;
y = yuv[position.y * size.width + position.x];
u = yuv[(position.y / 2) * (size.width / 2) + (position.x / 2) + size.total];
v = yuv[(position.y / 2) * (size.width / 2) + (position.x / 2) + size.total + (size.total / 4)];
```

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

Answer (score 5):

The diagram from thiagolr is very accurate.  An accurate diagram that looks more like yours would be

[image: Y U V layout]

The reason yours looks like it has 4 pictures is as explained by Hans Passant.