# How to create a Image or Mat instance from a YUV_420_888 byte array in EmguCV?

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

**The problem:**
I receive a YUV_420_888 image from an android device as a byte buffer (simply concatenated the image plane buffers). I know the dimension of the image and I need to display it onto my GUI.

**What I have so far:**
At the moment I can use only the grayscale Y-plane with the following function:

```
private BitmapImage GetImageFromBuffer(byte[] imgBuffer)
{
    Image<Gray, byte> emguImg = new Image<Gray, byte>(1280, 720);
    emguImg.Bytes = imgBuffer;

    var img = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(emguImg.ToJpegData()))
    {
        img.BeginInit();
        img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        img.StreamSource = ms;
        img.EndInit();
    }
    return img;
}
```

I also have tested a similar code, using `Image.ToBitmap()` function and copying the intermediate Bitmap to the memory stream, which serves as source for the `BitmapImage`.
Anyway, I would like to create a `BitmapImage` of `BitmapSource` (or any type I can use to display on the GUI) from the incoming `byte[]`.
As far as I could read up on it, I have to create a `Mat` instance from the byte array, convert it to RGB  and then save it to a diplay-able format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code seems to do the trick:

```
private BitmapImage GetImageFromBuffer(byte[] imgBuffer)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* p = imgBuffer)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)p;
            Mat yuvMat = new Mat(1080, 1280, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv8U, 1, ptr, 1280);
            Mat rgbMat = new Mat();
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(yuvMat, rgbMat, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Yuv420Sp2Rgb);
            var img = new BitmapImage();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.BeginInit();
                rgbMat.Bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
                img.StreamSource = ms;
                img.EndInit();
            }
            return img;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can confirm, if this is the way to go or comment suggestions for improvements.

Comment: Hey there, based on the code in your question looks like your image resolution is 720p, but in your answer here you use 1080 and 1280 as "rows" and "cols." Is that based on a different image resolution, or is there some calculation you did to get those numbers?

Comment: Apologies, I found the answer: apparently one multiplies the image width by 1.5 to get the "1080" value in the function.

Comment: Exactly, this is due to the way YUV image format is layed out :)
Here is a nice illustration, that shows why you need to multiply with 1.5:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822017/planar-yuv420-data-layout